Force std::stringstream to use \r\n as line ending
I'm adding some lines into a std::stringstream with stream << "content" << std::endl. Then I'm getting the content by stream.str().
If added a line with std::endl into a std::stringstream this will use \n as a line ending.
Is it possible to force std::stringstream to use a specific line ending as "\r\n", if added with std::endl?
(I don't want to insert an explicit stream << "\r\n" .)

AFAIK know this is platform depended. Just open stream in text mode (done implicitly there is a binary flag if you which disable text mode) and on Windows it should do it implicitly.

Is there any reason why you don't want to insert "\r\n" ?

AFAIK std::endl was never meant to write \r carriage return. It's \n line ending + buffer flush. For me it behaved as expected.

In C++ strings (and in C), the end of a line is marked with '\n'. When you write text to the console the output library writes the system-specific line-ending sequence to the console. On windows, writing "\n" to the console produces "\r\n"; on Unix systems it's just plain "\n", and on older Macs (if I remember correctly) it's just plain "\r". When you read text from the console the input library does the reverse transformation, converting the system-specific line ending sequence into '\n'. So, why do you want to write a line ending that doesn't match what your OS expects?

Why do you need "\r\n" in the first place? Maybe (depends on your answer) your question is a XY Problem

@Pete, one possibility is that we're composing a request to a network server that needs CR character at end of each line.  But that's pure speculation on my part.

@TobySpeight Yes. Thats correct. Inserting into stream shouldn't matter about line ending types. but getting the content of the stream should be with a specific line ending.

FYI... it will insert only a \n into the string buffer, but when you use the std library functions to save to disk or most io, assuming you didn't specify binary mode, it will translate \n to \r\n to on Windows.  What are you really trying to do?

Per [iostream.manip] the behavior of std::endl; is defined to insert the '\n' character only (and then flush the stream).
If you want identical behavior, but to always insert "\r\n" instead of '\n' then I suppose you could construct a custom manipulator like so:
#include <iostream>

template<class CharT, class Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& crlf(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os)
{
    return os.put(os.widen('\r'))
        .put(os.widen('\n'))
        .flush();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl; // always "\n"
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << crlf; // always "\r\n"
}

Demo
N.B. The calls to os.widen are in order to mimic the behavior of the endl manipulator.

To be more equivalent to std::endl, should this not insert "\r\n", flush the stream, then return os?

@Chris good point I'll add that.
